# Using Linux machine as a monitor for a Windows machine

Tags: linux, xorg, windows, hardware

What software do I need if I want to use an old laptop running Linux as a second monitor for a Windows 10 PC? Both screens shoud be in one workspace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a bit of research I found a program called [Spacedesk](http://spacedesk.ph/). The primary machine has to be Windows, but the secondary can be a phone, tablet, or PC running Windows / Linux.

Comment: Would be great to point out, that SpaceDesk Client can run though Wine on the Linux machine.

Comment: Spacedesk no longer supports Linux. not even with Windows 7 WMI and launching via Wine doesn't work.

Comment: I just set it up with Windows on the main machine and Linux on the laptop. You just run the spacedesk client through the browser. Works great!! :-)