# Use Linux laptop as second display

Tags: windows, display

I have 2 laptops, one Linux and one Windows. I want to use the Linux one as a second display but I can't find anything about it. I found this:

[Using Linux machine as a monitor for a Windows machine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/309098/using-linux-machine-as-a-monitor-for-a-windows-machine)

but Spacedesk dosent support linux anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that you've two different computers, one is running Windows and the other is running Linux. And you want to share the mouse and keyboard between them. [Synergy](https://symless.com/synergy/home) looks like the application you need. You may find more applications which can share mouse, keyboard and clipboard between computers.

Answer (score 2):

Although Spacedesk does not provide a native Linux client, I have had success with two different solutions:

- the Windows 7 version of the viewer runs well under Wine
- the HTML5 viewer seems to work fine also on desktop Linux, albeit the performance is noticeably worse than  of the native client